# Unexplained null and circular dependency in App Insights for Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to experiment with Azure App Insights, following this [tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-add-application-insights-to-an-angular-spa/). Unfortunately, I am totally new to Angular while experienced with the old Angularjs. The tutorial seems enough old-dated, I am working with Angular 10.

The concept is that in order to log errors (and possibly other analytics events) in an Angular application we can leverage the [Azure Insights SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/applicationinsights-js#configuration)

The tutorial creates a very-well-engineered service, that they called `MyMonitoringService` and I took freedom to rename `AnalyticsService`. So I just copied the fragment from the tutorial and renamed the class (saving as `analytics.service.ts`). I also had to import `Injectable` otherwise VS Code will report me an error.

I also created the same (!) `ErrorHandlerService` (`error.handler.service.ts`). Exclamation mark because I first `extend`ed Angular's `ErrorHandler`, then tried to `implement` with same result

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AnalyticsService } from './analytics.service';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {

    constructor(private loggingService: AnalyticsService) {
    }

    handleError(error: Error) {
        this.loggingService.logException(error); // Manually log exception
    }
}
```

From my understanding of Angular, I have declared a service which implements an interface and DI-depends on the `AnalyticsService`. Note that I called the variable `loggingService` because I believe there is a glitch in the documentation, nothing prevents me to call the field `analyticsService`, indeed it's intuitive and appropriate.

I continued with the tutorial and of course I knew I had to inject the service somewhere. The tutorial says to find the relevant `NgModule` and inject the error handler. Of course, the project I am working on is not empty.

The following is a fragment of the `app.component.ts` (look for `// <<<<<< added` comments)

```
import { AnalyticsService } from './shared/analytics.service'; // <<<<<< added

/** Main component of the application. Ensures that the user is authenticated first, then renders the main sections and enables the routes */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  /** Ensure that the user has completed the authentication process */
  public isAuthenticationComplete = false;
  /** Tells if the user is authenticated, to proceed in template rendering of contents */
  public isAuthenticated = false;
  /** User object */
  public user!: User;
  /** Tells if an http error happened */
  public serverError = false;
  /** List of links displayed on header component */
  public headerLinks: HeaderLink[] = [];
  /** Title of the application */
  public appTitle = 'My Sample App';

  /**
   * Dependency injection
   * @param titleService Angular Title
   * @param authenticationService Helper service that manage the user authentication
   * @param router Used to ravigate to a different route
   */
  constructor(
    private titleService: Title,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router,
    private analytics: AnalyticsService // <<<<<< added
  ) {
    this.authenticationService.appTitle = this.appTitle;
   }

  /** Handles the authentication of the user */
  ngOnInit() {
```

And the following is my whole `app.module.ts`

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AUTH_CONFIG, AuthenticationService } from 'rtop-angular-smart-widget';
import { authenticationConfig } from './app-auth-config';
import { httpInterceptorProviders } from './shared/interceptors';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ErrorHandlerService } from './shared/error.handler.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    httpInterceptorProviders,
    AuthenticationService,
    { provide: AUTH_CONFIG, useValue: authenticationConfig },
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorHandlerService }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

## The problem

When I launch the application from browser, I get the following error

```
main.ts:12 NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ApplicationModule -> ApplicationRef -> ErrorHandler -> AnalyticsService -> AnalyticsService -> AnalyticsService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for AnalyticsService!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:25357:27)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35505:33)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35505:33)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35505:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:25243:33)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:25247:57)
    at Object.ErrorHandlerService_Factory [as factory] (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1778:162)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35672:35)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35494:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:25243:33)
```

I don't understand why the `AnalyticsService` has a self reference in this stack trace, given that

1. I just copied the fragment, added the proper import for `Injectable` and renamed `MyMonitoringService` to a proper `AnalyticsService`
2. There are no self references in the code
3. Here is my code if you don't believe the above

.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApplicationInsights } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class AnalyticsService {
  appInsights: ApplicationInsights;
  constructor() {
    this.appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
      config: {
        instrumentationKey: environment.appInsights.instrumentationKey,
        enableAutoRouteTracking: true // option to log all route changes
      }
    });
    this.appInsights.loadAppInsights();
  }

  logPageView(name?: string, url?: string) { // option to call manually
    this.appInsights.trackPageView({
      name: name,
      uri: url
    });
  }

  logEvent(name: string, properties?: { [key: string]: any }) {
    this.appInsights.trackEvent({ name: name}, properties);
  }

  logMetric(name: string, average: number, properties?: { [key: string]: any }) {
    this.appInsights.trackMetric({ name: name, average: average }, properties);
  }

  logException(exception: Error, severityLevel?: number) {
    this.appInsights.trackException({ exception: exception, severityLevel: severityLevel });
  }

  logTrace(message: string, properties?: { [key: string]: any }) {
    this.appInsights.trackTrace({ message: message}, properties);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are not providing your `AnalyticsService` anywhere, at least I didn't find it in the code that you presented. Either add it to the module that is going to use it, or

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-41ajy7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update**

In the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#hierarchical-injectors) it's said how to inject:

> Using the @Injectable() providedIn property to refer to @NgModule(), or root.
> Using the @NgModule() providers array.

Comment: `Either add it to the module that is going to use it` how? I mean, since I am learning Angular too, how do I expose the component without using `providedIn: 'root'` syntax? The tutorial didn't add the service to the module directly. The tutorial added the error reporting service. Or do I just have to `import`?

Comment: You have to write it in the providers array, same as AuthenticationService. In the tutorial there probably was a provideIn

Comment: I `provide`d the `ErrorHandlerService`, which in turn depends on the `AnalyticsService`. I assume that Angular DI framework creates an internal resolution chain recursively. Since I read very few providers in my `NgModule`, I believed that is not the place to declare all services

Comment: Well evidently you still need to explicitly provide it either in the `providers` array or in the `Injectable`

Comment: You can also provide it in the component directly https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action